# Fixing div misalignment due to scroll-bar not showing in iOS

Tags: css, ios

I'm trying to align two divs, one that can scroll horizontally and one that cannot:

[image]

In desktop browsers I've been able to align them by just substracting 14px (the height I've set for the scroll-bar) from the height of the second div.

But in mobile this causes the divs to be misaligned since the scrollbar is not there and no longer needs to be accounted for.

[image]

If we could align the divs in iOS without the scroll-bar that'd be ideal but it would also be acceptable to simply show the scroll-bar in mobile.

Here is the css

```
.calendar-columns {
    /*div 1*/
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px 0%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.calendar-horizontal-total {
    /*div 2*/
    height: calc(100%-14px);
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that scroll bars aren't always 14px even on the same desktop computer. Safari on Mac OS treats scroll bars similarly to how iOS does but Firefox does not. Also, hights won't be consistent across OSes like Windows, Mac OS, Ubuntu, etc.

All that said, why not just use a media query to determine the display? Apply your height magic on desktop but not mobile.

```
@media (pointer: course) AND (max-width: 600) {
 styles for most phones
}
```

You'll have to play with the media queries to get exactly the devices you want.

Your other option would be to always force the scrollbar. It doesn't look great but it would solve your alignment issues.

`overflow-x: scroll`